# Executing new threads in order

Tags: android, multithreading, executorservice

Let me simplify my example. Imagine I have two buttons.

```
btn_A.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                // update ROOM DB value to A
            });
btn_B.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                // update ROOM DB value to B
            });
```

Button A will set DB value to 'A'.
Button B will set DB value to 'B'.

Since I cannot access DB from the Main/UI thread, I execute it from the new thread:

```
btn_A.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    new Thread(() -> {
        // update ROOM DB value to A
    }).start();
});
btn_B.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    new Thread(() -> {
        // update ROOM DB value to B
    }).start();
});
```

If I press Button A, B, A, B..., then I am worried that new threads will not execute consecutively(in sequence).

I thought about using ExecutorService with Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1) but I am not sure if this will run the worker thread in sequence. Also the DB modification commends are called from different Activities/Service so I should make the ExecutorService static. I am worried if I make the ExecutorService static and don't call 'shutdown()', then it may result in memory leak.

I want to avoid implementing my own producer/consumer design pattern with the queue logic.

It feels like there is a simple way to do it but I can't figure it out. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run all updates on a single thread. One way is to use `Looper` and `Handler` in order to send messages to the database update thread and it executes those messages in the order received. At a higher level, you can use an event bus library like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to help facilitate this inter-thread communication.